# How to use latest openssl library with pyOpenSSL?

Tags: python, openssl, pyopenssl

I am currently using [pyOpenssl](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyOpenSSL), and it uses openssl `1.0.1f` which is installed by system. now I install openssl `1.0.1j` from source, and set new version library path into `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, at this time, when I running my py file, it will produce error:

```
File "sslcert.py", line 5, in <module>
from OpenSSL import SSL, _util, crypto
...

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cffi-0.8.6-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/cffi/vengine_cpy.py", line 149, in load_library
    raise ffiplatform.VerificationError(error)
cffi.ffiplatform.VerificationError:  
importing '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography-0.6.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/cryptography/_Cryptography_cffi_36a40ff0x2bad1bae.so':    
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography-0.6.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/cryptography/_Cryptography_cffi_36a40ff0x2bad1bae.so:  
symbol EC_GFp_nistp521_method, version OPENSSL_1.0.1 not defined in file libcrypto.so.1.0.0 with link time reference
```

I am wonder using latest openssl library for pyOpenssl, How can fix this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably need to recompile [**cryptography**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cryptography) against the newer version of OpenSSL.

Make sure you install the development headers for OpenSSL as well and then rebuild (perhaps most easily by just re-installing) **cryptography**.

The way you upgrade OpenSSL will vary depending on your platform.  On Debian-derived systems this will probably be something like `apt-get install libssl-dev` (this will get you the library and development headers).  On RedHat-derived systems it might be more like `yum install libssl-devel`.

You may want to investigate the use of [**virtualenv**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) for this to keep your newly built versions separate from the already installed versions.

Once you have a virtualenv, you can install **cryptography** using pip:

```
path/to/virtualenv/bin/pip install cryptography
```

Or you can upgrade an existing installation:

```
path/to/virtualenv/bin/pip install --upgrade cryptography
```

Also note that the cryptography project [now ships **manylinux1** wheels](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/#building-cryptography-on-linux).  These are binary packages which include all dependencies - including OpenSSL.  Therefore, if you are on a platform which can use a **manylinux1** wheel, you do not need a separate OS installation of OpenSSL or its development headers.

Comment: Could you specify some sample commands to either recompile cryptography or reinstall it?

Comment: added some more specifics - but also note the new manylinux1 part of the answer.  times have changed.